# Expand a range of values given as a string to a comma separated string of values

Tags: r, stringr, mutate

A column of strings contains one or more numbers separated by commas or by a range (specifically, something like `5551-6` meaning 5551 through 5556). I need to expand the range to be in the same comma separated form as the other rows.

I have a work-around, but I am not happy with the complexity of it.

### Data Source

I have a character column of NAICS codes from [this table](https://www.bls.gov/emp/tables/industry-employment-and-output.htm). Which is the sheet named "Table 2.11" of the excel file available on the linked page.

The problem can be reproduced using the following sample data:

```r
data0 <- tibble::tibble("2022 NAICS" = c("31-33", "331", "332, 333", "6113", "6114-7", "6118"))
```

### Problem

Some of the rows contain multiple codes (for instance, `313, 314`). This is fine. I can separate these each into their own row with `separate_longer_delim(NAICS, delim = ", ")`. One row contains `6114-7`, which would be the NAICS codes 6114 through 6117. I would like to convert `6114-7` to the same form as the other rows. Since there is only one instance of the problem, I know I could explicitly replace that string, but I would like to do it dynamically.

### Desired Result

Convert NAICS codes given as a range (`6114-7`) to comma separated values as a string (`6114, 6115, 6116, 6117`).

### Attempt

I have a work-around, but I'm sure there is a more elegant solution. Ideally a solution that can also handle a different number of digits, such as turning `31-33` into `31, 32, 33`, which also appears in the data. I removed them in the attempt below.

The thought process in the `mutate` below is to find any rows similar to `6114-7`, and if found, paste a string which is formed by collapsing a sequence whose endpoints are extracted from the original value. If a match is not found, `NAICS` is set equal to itself, no changes are made.

```r
library(tidyverse)

data1 <- data0 |>
    rename(NAICS = "2022 NAICS") |>
    filter(!is.na(NAICS), NAICS != "NA") |>
    filter(str_detect(NAICS,"(\\d\\d)-(\\d\\d)",negate = TRUE)) |>
    rowwise() |>
    mutate(
        NAICS = ifelse(
            str_detect(NAICS, "(\\d+)-(\\d)"),
            paste(
                as.numeric(
                    str_extract(NAICS, "(\\d+)", group = 1)
                ):(
                    round(
                        as.numeric(
                            str_extract(NAICS, "(\\d+)", group = 1)
                        ),
                        digits = -1
                    ) +
                        as.numeric(
                            str_extract(NAICS, "-(\\d)", group = 1)
                        )
                ),
                collapse = ", "
            ),
            NAICS
        )
    )

# using data0 provided above, data1 is:
# A tibble: 5 × 1
# Rowwise: 
#  NAICS                 
#  <chr>                 
# 1 331                   
# 2 332, 333              
# 3 6113                  
# 4 6114, 6115, 6116, 6117
# 5 6118
```

Comment: I just want to check - in your text the examples of `-` codes only has a single digit after the dash, `51-5` and `6114-7`. However in your sample data we see `31-33` with two digits after the dash, even though the first digit is the same. So, two questions (a) is there any restriction/consistency on the number of digits after the dash? (b) Is it possible to have > 10 ranges after the dash, e.g. `101-21` meaning 101:121?

Comment: I dont understand your issue. it seems like you have a method, but believed it didnt cover the 31-33 case, but if we remove your filter (the one with the negate) and simply try the code, it does ...

Comment: @GregorThomas To answer (a), yes. There is only ever one or two digits after the dash. If prior to the dash there are exactly two digits, there must be two digits after. If prior to the dash there are >2 digits, then after the dash would be only one digit. To answer (b), the values are a hierarchical categorization, so no, `101-21` would not be possible in this dataset.

Comment: @NirGraham You are correct for the case `31-33` since the first and second digit of 33 are the same, but this fails if we have something like `31-34` instead.

Comment: so that would have been great to put in your data :)

Comment: *"If prior to the dash there are exactly two digits, there must be two digits after."* So `51-5` is **not** a valid example after all?

Comment: @GregorThomas Sorry, disregard `51-5`, my mistake. I'll adjust the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me that if the second number in a pair separated by a `-` is less than 10, we can assume that it is supposed to represent a value with the same number of 10s as the first value. Otherwise, it is treated as-is. For example `975-6` would represent `975, 976` and `51-5` would represent `51, 52, 53, 54, 55`, but the latter could also be represented with `51-55`.

That being the case, we can do:

```r
unlist(lapply(strsplit(data0$`2022 NAICS`, '-'), \(x) {
  if(length(x) == 2) {
    x <- as.numeric(x)
    if(x[2] < 10) x[2] <- 10 * floor(x[1]/10) + x[2]
    paste(seq(as.numeric(x[1]), as.numeric(x[2])), collapse = ', ')
  } else x
}))
#> [1] "31, 32, 33"             "331"                    "332, 333"              
#> [4] "6113"                   "6114, 6115, 6116, 6117" "6118"
```